# Selenium get position of the page relative to the beginning of page

Tags: c#, selenium, position

I am using Selenium remotewebdriver with Nunit and c#. When I find an error, I want to be able to scroll to the location where the error occured and then take the screenshot. This is how I want to implement this method.

```
public void ScrollToLocation(Point location)
{
    //code to find position of the page
    var windowLocation = code to find position

    var yOffset = location.Y - windowLocation.Y;

    IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)webDriver;
    js.ExecuteScript("javascript:window.scrollBy(0," + yOffset + ")");
}
```

The problem is that I do not know how to find the relative location of the page. For example, if the page is scrolled down so that the top left corner of the page seen on my screen is 50px down from the (0,0) location of the entire page, I want to find 50.

I have thought of a work around where I just scroll up by 10000px and then scroll down by location.Y, but I am not a fan of this.

edit: I forgot to mention, due to reasons, I cannot use GetElementLocationOnceScrolledIntoView

Comment: Do you actually have to scroll? Is just taking a screenshot at the current point not enough? Have you tried that? I've ever come across a situation where you have to explicitly scroll to get something done.

Comment: Are you able to take a screenshot at a particular point? If so then that will solve my problem. This is how I am taking my screenshots.


Response screenshotResponse = this.Execute(DriverCommand.Screenshot, null);
            string base64 = screenshotResponse.Value.ToString();